# Can't explain result of that pattern

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns, prototype

Can someone explain to me the result of my code, I don't understand what's happening here..

here is the code :

```
var myObj = (function() {


    var testPatt = function(params) {
         jQuery.extend(this.options, this.defaults, params);
    };

    testPatt.prototype = {
        constructor : testPatt,
        options : {},
        defaults : {}
    };

    return testPatt;
})();

var title1 = new myObj({ "title" : "mon titre" });
var title2 = new myObj({ "title" : "mon titre 2ème edition" });

console.log(title1.options.title) //--> "mon titre 2ème edition"; ???????
```

I expect console to write "mon titre" but the result is "mon titre 2ème edition", I can't explain why...

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nJDtb/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one prototype, and that is shared between the instances.

So each time you create a new object, the "global" options (stored in the prototype) is overwritten.

Comment: Thanks Karoly, after reading your answer and making some searches It looks like it's a singleton pattern... how should I rewrite my code to allow multiple instances of myObj ?

Comment: huh? the singleton pattern enforces that there's at any time at most a single object of a class. if you want multiple instances, *don't use this pattern*